# Installing PHP5.4 on Centos 5.8

Tags: php, linux, centos

Attempting to upgrade from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 using a tutorial found at http://www.how2centos.com/installing-php-5-4-on-centos-5-8/.  I basically says to do the following:

```
yum install yum-priorities
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-10.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
yum install php54 php54-common php54-devel
```

When executing the second line, I get the following error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
error: skipping http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
warning: u 0xc073650 ctrl 0xc074a20 nrefs != 0 (download.fedoraproject.org http)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: do you have an internet connexion???  and can't you do something like yum update, becuase you're saying you're updating...

Comment: Yes, I have internet connection.  Can I update from 5.3 to 5.4, or only to most recent 5.3 version?

Comment: Tried just yum update, but didn't address php

Comment: hmmm, how did you install php before then?

Comment: rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm

Comment: Mayby is this helpfull? http://serverfault.com/questions/255950/force-update-php-version-wont-update-from-5-1-6-ssh

Comment: Thanks, but not ready to update to Centos 5.6 today.  Louis's answer worked.

Comment: alright, glad that that worked :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because download.fedoraproject.org is redirecting to a mirror. RPM in RHEL 5 doesn't follow that (yet).
Try to replace it with a direct hostname (dl.fedoraproject.org for example).

Comment: rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm worked.  First had to remove old PHP using yum remove php php-cgi php-cli php-common